# How To Insert Facebook Conversion Pixel Into Head Tag Using Yii Framework?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, yii

Anyone have idea how to insert this code in header tag?

I using Yii Framework.

by my reading it can be done using CClientScript

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for cashout -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'XXXX';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'MYR';
(function(){
var fpw = document.createElement('script');
fpw.async = true;
fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"     src="facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=XXXX&amp;value=0&amp;currency=MYR" /></noscript>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add this to your view/layout/xxx.php file. You can embed plain Javascript into your views.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it any where in your views, but if you do that it will be only available in that place

if you want to have yii handle it, you can go like this

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myCustomScript', "

var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'XXXX';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'MYR';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();

");
```

Comment: your about code below? how to together with above code?

    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=XXX&amp;value=0&amp;currency=MYR" /></noscript>;